# Flutter Awaesome Notification actionStrem Listen

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification, awesome-notifications

I am using flutter and for local notification awesome-notification package. I create a notification and send it to the user. When the user clicks on the notification, I will redirect to another page.
When the notification that comes on every page of the application is clicked, I will direct you to the page. but this code only listens on the page I put. Where should I put it to listen on each page?

```
AwesomeNotifications()
      .actionStream
      .listen((ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    if (channels.contains(receivedNotification.channelKey)) {
      print('event received!');
      print(receivedNotification.toMap().toString());
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => OrganizerNotificationScreen(
              taskId: receivedNotification.id.toString(),
              taskBody: receivedNotification.body,
              taskChannel: receivedNotification.channelKey,
            ),
          ));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen on all pages of your application, run this code in the `initState` of the first page.
and use `static` and `async` `await`